# read-syntax sets line/column numbers to #f

Tags: racket

When parsing syntax from a string input port, all line/column numbers get set to `#f`. Why is that?

```lisp
(let* ([port (open-input-string "123")]
       [stx (read-syntax "my-input" port)])
  (printf "line ~a column ~a" (syntax-line stx) (syntax-column stx))
)
```

Expected output:

`line 1 column 0`

[Actual output](https://jdoodle.com/ia/u4K):

`line #f column #f`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to explicitly turn on [line based location tracking](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/linecol.html) for ports, for example by setting the [`port-count-lines-enabled` parameter](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/linecol.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._port-count-lines-enabled%29%29):

```lisp
(parameterize ([port-count-lines-enabled #t])
  (let* ([port (open-input-string "123")]
         [stx (read-syntax "my-input" port)])
    (printf "line ~a column ~a" (syntax-line stx) (syntax-column stx))))
```

which prints

```
line 1 column 0
```

There's also [`port-count-lines!`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/linecol.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._port-count-lines%21%29%29) for enabling it on existing ports.

Comment: Nice. I didn't even consider that this might be a property of the _port_ rather than the reader.